# Copy content of one table to another, where column content is different

Tags: mysql, copy

I need to copy the content of a source table (val & name columns) to a target table (Using MySQL).

However, I only wish to copy the content if the val fields in the source table are different to the val fields in the target table.

I have the following so far:

**QUERY**

```
INSERT INTO target_tbl (val, name) SELECT val, name source_tbl WHERE [CODE_HERE];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **QUERY**

```
INSERT INTO target_tbl 
(
   val, name
) 
SELECT val, name source_tbl
FROM source_tbl  
WHERE val 
NOT IN 
(
   SELECT val FROM target_tbl 
)
```

Comment: Perfect. Just noticed that I missed a FROM on the code I supplied. Fully working code should be: INSERT INTO target_tbl (val, name) SELECT val, name FROM source_tbl WHERE val NOT IN (SELECT val FROM target_tbl);